# Is the current number of confirmations visible somewhere in the raw block?

Tags: transactions, confirmations, block, raw-data

Is the current number of confirmations visible somewhere in the raw block output created by blockexplorer or blockhain.info?

Is this information available in the raw stream or is the number of confirmations always "live" calculated by counting the confirmations and not "saved" in the raw stream?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The number of confirmations is (height of most recent block - height of the block containing the transaction + 1). The contents of the specific block containing the transaction are fixed, while the number of confirmations keeps increasing, so the number of confirmations cannot be in the raw block data.

Comment: The genesis block had a height of 0.  The next block had a height of 1.  And so on.  It's the "block number".  There can be multiple blocks with the same number, such as when two miners solve a block at around the same time.

Comment: @ChrisMoore: What's the context of this comment?

Comment: @MeniRosenfeld I asked "what is height of the block". I found out the correct answer a few minutes later and deleted my question. Chris Moore probably answered at the same time as I delete my question.

Comment: I was answering a comment which asked "what is the height of a block"?  The comment was later deleted.